# Can I get a value other then 0 or 1 that tells me how dark or light the room is without using a capacitor?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I have connected a photoresistor to a raspberry pi. My code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(4, gpio.IN)

while True:
    input_value = gpio.input(4)
    print "Input value " , input_value
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The output is constantly 1 and only goes to zero if and only if the photoresistor is covered completely. I know that a capacitor will be beneficial but I was wondering if there was a way around this.

PS-: I am aware that raspberry pi can't sense the analogue values, I am looking for a look around if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply You Can't.

But you can use a potentiometer to calibrate the output (just a workaround).

Create a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) circuit with with one potentiometer. and you can calibrate output voltage from sensor i.e input to the Pi using potentiometer.